# Remover o background de uma imagem - python

Tags: python, processamento-de-imagens, opencv

Estou elaborando um código para remover o background de uma imagem, estou tentando usar o detector de fronteira Canny para elaborar uma máscara e tentar remover um pedaço de tubulação da imagem:

[image: Tubulação]

O código que estou trabalhando é esse:

```
img = imread('Imagem.jpg')
gray = cvtColor(img,COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = Canny(gray,10,100) #Utiliza o metodo Canny
edges = dilate(edges, None) # Dilata as linhas da fronteira
edges = erode(edges, None) # remove pequenos "buracos"

contour_info = []
contours, _ = findContours(edges, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for c in contours:
    contour_info.append((c, isContourConvex(c),contourArea(c), ))
contour_info = sorted(contour_info, key=lambda c: c[2], reverse=True) 
max_contour = contour_info[0]

mask = np.zeros(edges.shape)
fillConvexPoly(mask, max_contour[0], (255))

mask_stack = np.dstack([mask]*3)    # Cria uma mascara de 3 canais

mask_stack  = mask_stack.astype('float32') / 255.0           
img = img.astype('float32') / 255.0
Mscor = (1.0,1.0,1.0) # Formato BGR                 

masked = (mask_stack * img) + ((1-mask_stack) * Mscor) 
masked = (masked * 255).astype('uint8')
```

sendo o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

já tentei ajustar os gradientes da função `cv2.Canny`, mas só piora, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Dê uma olhada: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29314286/664577

Comment: Vc já deu uma olhada na imagem que resulta da aplicação do Canny? Ela pode te ajudar a fazer um ajuste fino dos parâmetros dessa chamada. O que te interessa são as bordas entre o pedaço de tubulação e o restante da imagem, e não as demais possíveis bordas existentes (talvez na textura do papelão, mas certamente entre o branco e o marrom da caixa).

Comment: Outra coisa: as tubulações sempre têm cores distintas da caixa onde estão? Se sim, vc já tentou uma [limiarização](http://paginas.fe.up.pt/~padilha/PAI/ficheiros/Cap4-ac.pdf) do histograma de cores? Pode ser suficiente para o seu problema.

Comment: Bom, como você não respondeu aos meus comentários, eu vou votar pra fechar como não clara. Deixo também o mesmo puxão de orelha que já deixei [em outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137686/73) (que, aliás, talvez até te ajude com o problema em si): se você não se importa em facilitar o entendimento, é difícil que alguém tenha interesse em te ajudar.

Comment: Estava bastante ocupado esses dias, aí não deu para ler direito os comentários, irei testar as dicas e quando obter uma solução irei por o código nesta pergunta para que outros possam usar. Desculpe e obrigado Luiz Vieira