# Como converter imagem colorida em preta e branco e destacar somente as brancas de um video

Tags: python, processamento-de-imagens, opencv

Eu gostaria de destacar a cor branca usando webcam e opencv python, porem minha imagem é colorida, primeiramente preciso converter para preto e branco e daí gostaria de destacar somente as brancas, que serão os objetos detectados da imagem. Eu já tenho o código que detecta a cor branca.

A imagem é esta, onde tem alguns pontos pretos, são esses pontos que quero destacar e poder separar do restante da imagem. 
[image: erro]

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of white color in HSV
    # change it according to your need !
    lower_white = np.array([0,0,0], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_white = np.array([0,0,255], dtype=np.uint8)

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only white colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white)
    # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Comment: Olá Carlos. A sua pergunta não está muito clara. No seu código vc *já converte* a imagem para preto e branco ao binarizá-la com o `inRange`, não? Além disso, quando vc diz "destacar" o que quer dizer? Mudar a cor do que for branco? Eu sugeriria você fornecer um exemplo da imagem que vai processar e dos "objetos" que quer detectar. Outra coisa, já deu uma olhada nas questões que já existem na tag [tag:opencv]?

Comment: Alguma ajuda Luiz?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Nota: Este é apenas um pequeno "puxão de orelha" que você merece, antes da resposta efetivamente.
>
> Esta já não é a sua primeira pergunta por aqui, e eu já
>   te disse algumas vezes que *este site não é um fórum*. Não é todo
>   membro da comunidade que tem paciência e mesmo disponibilidade pra
>   ficar perguntando e descobrindo as informações relevantes aos poucos.
>   Nas suas próximas perguntas, continue sendo objetivo, mas procure fazê-lo sem perder a clareza. Forneça logo de cara todas as informações
>   que você julgar relevantes para que alguém consiga te ajudar (em casos
>   como o desta pergunta, isso inclui exemplos da imagem a ser processada 
>   e da imagem resultante, trecho relevante do código - ou, melhor ainda, 
>   um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - ilustração clara do 
>   que é um "ponto preto", etc). Se as pessoas não entendem o seu
>   problema, elas simplesmente não conseguem te ajudar e podem acabar 
>   desistindo. Fica a dica. :)

Bom, o seu código demonstra claramente que você lê a imagem a partir de uma câmera. Pela qualidade da imagem, eu suponho que é tirada de uma câmera de celular ou de uma Webcam de baixa resolução. Não sei julgar o que essa imagem contém (talvez uma textura de pele de algum animal?), mas adianto que você provavelmente vai ter importantes dificuldades de processamento devido à baixa qualidade de captura. Observe como há linhas escuras paralelas - quase todas verticais, mas algumas diagonais - cortando toda a extensão da imagem. Elas não parecem ser características da textura original, e sim resultantes do processo de captura de imagem. Se for um trabalho profissional, talvez você precise se preocupar em adquirir/utilizar uma câmera melhor ou controlar a iluminação do ambiente.

Tendo dito isso, também não está claro o que você quer dizer com "pontos pretos" (que, em teoria, são o seu objeto de interesse que você quer segmentar dessa imagem). A palavra "ponto" poderia ser relacionada diretamente com pixels pretos, mas eu acho pouco provável que seja isso que você quer segmentar. Há as características que parecem com grãos de arroz, que são efetivamente mais escuras do que o restante da textura. Mas não são pretos. Fazendo algum esforço, pode-se talvez enxergar algumas manchas ainda mais escuras, porém mais pequenas. Enfim, como você não forneceu detalhes, ninguém além de você sabe exatamente o que vc quer. Mais um puxão de orelha: eu mesmo *quase não respondi* a essa pergunta simplesmente por isso.

O seu código funciona, ele talvez só não produza o que você deseja. Abaixo eu reproduzo uma imagem com a máscara e o resultado que o seu código produz:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como você pode observar, tanto as máscara como o resultado apresentam apenas alguns pequenos pontos brancos. O motivo é que você usou no seu código um limiar talvez pouco apropriado e de forma equivocada. Você fez o seguinte:

```
lower_white = np.array([0,0,0], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_white = np.array([0,0,255], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Esse trecho de código cria os limites inferiores (lower) e superiores (upper) para o filtro de criação da máscara, mas note como na segunda linha você usa `[0,0,255]`. A imagem colorida, no OpenCV é tratada como BGR (de B de blue/azul, G de green/verde e R de red/vermelho). O que você faz ali é literalmente eliminar completamente os valores dos canais azul (B, o primeiro) e verde (G, o segundo) ao fazer com que os limites inferior e superior sejam 0, e permite totalmente a "passagem" do canal vermelho (R, o terceiro) ao fazer com que o limite inferior seja 0 e o superior 255 (ou seja, tudo!). Por isso a sua imagem resultante contém apenas (e destacados em branco) os pixels que efetivamente tinham *algum valor de vermelho no pixel da imagem original*. Certamente não era o que vc queria.

Você tem resultados melhores com o seu código se usar o mesmo limiar para os três canais de cor (mas o ideal mesmo seria trabalhar com uma imagem convertida para escala de cinza - use `cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`). Eu fiz uma alteração no seu código para ilustrar o uso do mesmo limiar para os três canais. E, aliás, também usei a biblioteca [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) para produzir uma exibição melhorada com as três imagens lado a lado. Eis o código:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

frame = cv2.imread('teste.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

limiar = 127

# define range of white color in HSV
# change it according to your need !
lower_white = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_white = np.array([limiar, limiar, limiar], dtype=np.uint8)

# Threshold the HSV image to get only white colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white)
# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

titles = ['Imagem Original','Mascara','Resultado']
images = [frame, mask, res]

for i in xrange(3):
    plt.subplot(1,3,i+1), plt.imshow(images[i], 'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Note que nesse código eu defini o limiar como `limiar = 127` (mais ou menos a metade dos valores possíveis para um pixel - que vai de 0 a 255) em uma variável e uso a mesma para os três canais na construção de `upper_white`. O resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para fazer a limiarização, você também tem outras opções. Eu diria que são até melhores.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

limiar = 127
maximo = 255 

img = cv2.imread('teste.jpg', 0)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, limiar, maximo, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img, limiar, maximo, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
ret,thresh3 = cv2.threshold(img, limiar, maximo, cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)
ret,thresh4 = cv2.threshold(img, limiar, maximo, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
ret,thresh5 = cv2.threshold(img, limiar, maximo, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)

titles = ['Imagem Original','BINARY','BINARY_INV','TRUNC','TOZERO','TOZERO_INV']
images = [img, thresh1, thresh2, thresh3, thresh4, thresh5]

for i in xrange(6):
    plt.subplot(2,3,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Esse código gera o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse exemplo foi baseado na documentação do OpenCV. Lá tem até algumas opções mais avançadas, como o [thresholding (limiarização) adaptativo](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html#gsc.tab=0).

Finalmente, note como o resultado na primeira opção (binary - que é exatamente a mesma que se obtém usando `inRange` com o mesmo limiar para todos os canais) é melhor do que eu obtive com o seu código original. Isto ocorre por se ter usado nesse caso a imagem *já em escala de cinza* ao invés de colorida (ela já foi lida assim na chamada de `cv2.imread('teste.jpg', 0)` por causa do 0 no final, mas você pode converter uma imagem colorida para escala de cinza com `cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`, como já foi indicado anteriormente).

> Para saber mais sobre imagens coloridas, em escala de cinza e
>   binárias, eu sugiro também a leitura [desta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83606/73).

Comment: Luiz Muito obrigado pelas dicas, vou procurar melhorar minhas perguntas.

Comment: Por nada. :) Boa sorte! []s

Comment: @Luis Vieira voce pode me ajudar nessa pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211431/segmentar-imagem-e-destacar-borda-do-objeto-usando-python

Comment: Carlos, sua outra pergunta tem os mesmos problemas desta. Pra começar: o que é uma "palheta"? Qual "objeto" vc quer segmentar? Forneça exemplos do resultado esperado (nem que vc tenha que fazer manualmente). Forneça também mais detalhes do que vc tá fazendo. A sua imagem é em tons de cinza porque o hardware captura assim, ou vc tem informação de cor? Segmentação de imagens é um problema bastante amplo, e sua outra pergunta está,basicamente pedindo pra alguém fazer pra vc.

Comment: Mas indicar material de leitura é fácil: http://www.gpec.ucdb.br/sibgrapi2008/tutorials/tutorial-2.pdf Talvez vc possa usar um detector ao invés de tentar segmentar. O [Haar Cascade](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html) pode ser uma boa nesse caso, mas vc vai precisar treiná-lo com imagens de exemplos boas que contenham e não contenham a "palheta" (seja lá o que isso for). Ou seja, dá trabalho, mas funciona. Fica então essa outra dica de leitura: http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

Comment: Olá Luiz, essa imagem eh nesse tom pois eh conforme meu hardware captura. Quando fiz essa pergunta eu não tinha objeto que nesse caso eh um ovo de mosquito, nessa nova pergunta já tenho o objeto detectado pela câmera. Eu estou usando o haar cascade pra reconhecimento de objetos, inclusive ontem fiz 720 imagens positivas pra treinar o algoritmo, só que quero melhorar a imagem pra ficar mais fácil do haar detectar o ovo. Por Isso abri a nova pergunta. Já usei alguns conversores binários, limiarizaçao, watershed, e não obtive um bom resultado.

Comment: To pensando em tentar usar o haar assim msm com as imagens originais pra testar a efetividade do algoritmo.

Comment: Cara, se o Haar já detecta o objeto, pra que raios vc quer aplicar outros filtros? O Haar te devolve justamente a região onde ele encontrou o objeto. A facilidade de detecção com esse algoritmo não depende necessariamente de filtros previamente aplicados, mas sim das imagens de exemplo que você usou no treinamento. Lembre-se que pra ser capaz de detectar o tal ovo em diferentes direções, vc precisaria de imagens positivas também em diferentes posições. Leia lá o tutorial que eu indiquei. Boa sorte.