# Segmentar imagem e destacar borda do objeto usando python

Tags: python, processamento-de-imagens, opencv

Estou testando alguns algoritmos para melhorar a qualidade da imagem que meu hardware esta obtendo. Tenho na imagem uma palheta e gostaria de destacar o objeto contido nela.

[image: imagem obtida]

Usei o codigo abaixo para fazer a equalizaçao da imagem, mas nao obtive sucesso.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def histogram_equalize(img):
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
red = cv2.equalizeHist(r)
green = cv2.equalizeHist(g)
blue = cv2.equalizeHist(b)
return cv2.merge((blue, green, red))
img = cv2.imread('pos20.jpg')

img_yuv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)

# equalize the histogram of the Y channel
img_yuv[:,:,0] = cv2.equalizeHist(img_yuv[:,:,0])

# convert the YUV image back to RGB format
img_output = cv2.cvtColor(img_yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)

cv2.imshow('Color input image', img)
cv2.imshow('Histogram equalized', img_output)
cv2.imwrite('20.jpg',img_output)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Resultado de saida:

[image: saida]

qual o melhor algoritmo para melhorar a qualidade da imagem e destacar a borda do objeto?

Comment: Mas o resultada da equalização é isso mesmo, o problema ai é a imagem original, tente equalizar com o [Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518684/histogram-equalization-of-grayscale-images-with-numpy) e provavelmente o resultado sera muito paracido.

Comment: Sua pergunta tem muitos problemas, como eu já comentei anteriormente. Vc não diz exatamente o que é objeto, você não define o que é "qualidade" no se contexto, você não diz claramente a sua intenção (apenas diz que quer "destacar a borda do objeto"). Se vc quer destacar a borda, por que não usou um filtro sensível a bordas, como um [gradiente](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html) ou o famoso [Canny](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html) no lugar da equalização?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente essa imagem "tá osso", e sua pergunta mais ainda, :-), mas talvez aplicando algo mais relacionado à segmentação, vc possa ter resultados melhores.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('img1.jpg',0)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
ret,thresh3 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)
ret,thresh4 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
ret,thresh5 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)
titles = ['Original Image','BINARY','BINARY_INV','TRUNC','TOZERO','TOZERO_INV']
images = [img, thresh1, thresh2, thresh3, thresh4, thresh5]
for i in xrange(6):
    plt.subplot(2,3,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pronto eu utilizei o TRUNC, mas quando salvo a imagem acaba perdendo a qualidade e fica parecendo em escala de cinza somente

Comment: Para obter bons resultados em tratamento de imagens, sempre se incia em escala de cinza, nesse caso, qdo a imagem é carregada já é convertida para grayscale. Para segmentação o ideal é testar varios algoritmos. [Experimente essa lib](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/)

Comment: Otima dica Sidon, vai me ajudar bastante